# Disabling checkboxes in Dojo gridx/Grid

Tags: grid, dojo, dojo.gridx

I have a gridx/Grid (This is advanced and lighter that dojo DataGrid and Enhanced Grid). I use two layouts for this. One for enabled state and the other for disabled state. Based upon the conditions, respective layout will be used, when the page loads.

The checkbox for every row(the one added on left mist used for row selection), is not part of layout. They are added dynamically by the widget code, based on the number of rows in data returned by the ajax call.

So, we need to disable it manually. But, how do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do disable the row selector checkbox manually. We need to use the grid.select.row.setSelected() method, where grid is the Grid widget.

```
grid.select.row.setSelected(ROWID,BOOLEAN);
```

the first arg is mandatory, which is the value of idProperty of that row.
the second arg is a boolean, to either make it selectable("true") or not("false").
if we do not pass 2nd arg, false is taken by default.

`grid.select.row.setSelected("1");` => will disable the row selector chkbox of the row with id="1"

To enable it again,

```
grid.select.row.setSelected("1",true);
```

As of now, there is not a function to disable all. We need to loop through all rows one by one, for this case. The checkbox selector in header, which is used to select all rows at one, is not part of this, since it does not have an id. we need to disable it manually. The header checkbox loads initially and not data dependent and so it is doable as below:-

```
query(".gridxRowHeaderHeaderCell").style("visibility","hidden");
```

One more hack related to this:-
if grid.select.row.enable is set to false, user cannot select the checkbox, but appearance will not look as disabled. **It will look normal but user cannot select any rows.**

```
grid.select.row.enable = false;
```

If we want to revoke it and make all the rows selectable, just reset this to true.